# What are some scripting methods that could autofill an iPad?

Tags: ios, automation, scripting

I've recently went into a new IT job for my school and we're in the process of removing the activation lock on all of the school iPads. I was wondering if I could hook up my laptop (on Windows) to one of the iPads and run some sort of script (e.g. batch or Apple's auto) to select specified buttons upon entering the recovery setup and fill in each text entry with the necessary information.

Would this at all be possible? If so, what might I research to achieve it?

Originally I used the iPad digital keyboard which was tedious and very accident prone, then I switched to an attachable keyboard which helped quite a bit. However, if possible, I wish to find a quicker and easier way.

Comment: Are all of the iPads activation locked to a single iCloud account?  If so, it is probably easier to just log into that iCloud account in a web browser and remove the iPads.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes they are, although they all use remote management (filewave mdm) so there might be more steps than that

Comment: You need to know if the devices are supervised or under the DEP or just MDM managed and activation locked using iCloud.  This question would be better asked at [AskDifferent](https://apple.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Paulw11 I believe it's the latter, although I'd have to dig into deeper IT waters. I'll ask there as well, thanks!